# JQuery AJAX returns Error always

Tags: jquery

I have a jsp page which simply prints `{"result" : "success"}` and there is a php page which calls this jsp with JQUery AJAJAX as below

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $.ajax({
                              url: 'index.jsp',
                              data: 'id=test',
                              dataType: 'json',
                              cache: false,
                              async:true,
                              success: function(data) {
                                     alert(data);

                                  },
                                 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert('Error ' + xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);                                        
                                }
                });
            });
```

If I put url in browser it works fine . But this ajax request always goes to error block .

Is there any argument in ajax call wrong ? I get alert  'Error ' no other resoibse text or error code.

I have another exactly same call from a jsp page which worked fine !

Comment: and what is that alert looking like?

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug - open the "NET" tab and you can see the response from the server directly.

Comment: what happens if you replace "alert(data)" with "alert(data.result)" or "console.log(data)" ?

Comment: @Diodeus Yes I already did that it shows empty

Comment: Then something is wrong with your server-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that it was a cross domain call which was causing issue . I had to use jsonp and add a callback function in order for it to work .

Comment: This is probably the best answer (not the selected one on this page). Had the same issue and running the file on my server instead of locally fixed it. Definitely a cross domain security thing which strangely jquery doesn't give specific error message for.

Comment: This answer isn't good enough. It does not show what is meant by "use jsonp and add a callback function".

Comment: This is unclear: "use jsonp and add a callback function"